# Finding the IP Address of a computer (through a firewall)

Tags: ping, ip-address

I am looking for a way to find the IP address of a computer connected to a network.

The scenario is the following:

- The computer whose IP address I want to find is connected to the network.
- This computer uses a firewall
- The computer sets its IP dynamically.

I have read that you can use ping and nslookup for this. 
First, as a test, I tried ping and nslookup with a random hostname and I got their IP address as stated [here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000962.htm).

Then I tried, (just to test) this with a PC with a static IP. When I did

```
ping CompName
```

I got the IP address

however whenn I tried

```
nslookup CompName
```

I got
Can't file: Server failed

Even if I can do this with ping, what happens when the target computer is behind a firewall?

Comment: Define firewall. Most companies will put their computers behind soemthign that does NAT - then you can not even PING them.

Comment: nslookup only queries DNS where your system may be configured to both use other sources of name resolution and may appending a search domain to a bare hostname

Answer (score 0):

If the network is configured with dynamic DNS, the DHCP servers should register computers they’ve provided with IP addresses in the DNS database. Not all networks are, though.

The individual computer’s firewall status makes no difference to the DHCP servers ability to communicate with the DNS server.

Computers that are set up with static IP addresses may or may not get automatically registered with DNS depending on a number of circumstances and configuration options.

When it comes to actually communicating with computers after you’ve got their hostname or IP address, you naturally need to configure the firewall to allow some minimum amount of necessary inbound traffic. Preferably, from a security perspective, you’ll want the majority of traffic to be outbound from most computers rather than poking holes in the local firewall to allow fetching things directly from the outside. In the long term this will minimize your security management headaches. Successfully doing so would likely involve configuring management tools or -agents that allow you to remotely initiate outbound actions on the machines in a secure way.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a ping, you are first initiating a name resolution for the computer name. In modern Windows machines this will generally use 'host name resolution' although in some instances it will use 'NetBIOS resolution'.

### Host name resolution

Host name resolution generally uses the following sequence:

- The client checks to see if the name queried is its own.
- The client then searches a local Hosts file.
- Domain Name System (DNS) servers are queried.
- If the name is still not resolved, NetBIOS name resolution sequence may be used as a backup.

So, in the scenario you have raised, the target computer will definitely not be your computer (not 'locahost'). It is not likely to be in your local hosts file, unless you put it there, so we are reliant on either DNS or persuading the computer to tell you it's IP address.

NSLOOKUP is a tool to definitely query the DNS database of a chosen DNS server. @Mikael-H's answer explains why the dynamic IP address may or may not be found in the DNS database. If the answer is in DNS you will find it with NSLOOKUP, and if the conditions are not right for the dynamic IP to be found you should be able to fix this if you are in control of the network.

### DHCP Database

Of course, it is worth mentioning that if you have access to the DHCP server then you can lookup the name and IP of the computer in the DHCP database. It would help to know the MAC address of the computer or when it first requested an IP.

### ARP Resolution

If you know the MAC address of the target computer then you can easily find out the IP, even with quite strict firewalling in place. Send out a ping to the `broadcast address` (something like 192.168.2.255 on a /24 network). This will not resolve but follow up with a arp -a command and all the ARP entries on the subnet will be shown. You should see your target computer there.